# How to read a file starting at a specific cursor point in C#?

Tags: c#, file, file-io

I want to read a file but not from the beginning of the file but at a specific point of a file. For example I want to read a file after 977 characters after the beginning of the file, and then read the next 200 characters at once. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to read the file as text, skipping characters (not bytes):

```
using (var textReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(path))
{
    // read and disregard the first 977 chars
    var buffer = new char[977];
    textReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

    // read 200 chars
    buffer = new char[200];
    textReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

If you merely want to skip a certain number of bytes (not characters):

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
{
    // seek to starting point
    fileStream.Seek(977, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    // read 200 bytes
    var buffer = new byte[200];
    fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use **Linq** and converting array of char to string .

add these namespace :

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
```

then you can use this to get an array of characters **starting index a as much as b characters** from your text file :

```
char[] c = File.ReadAllText(FilePath).ToCharArray().Skip(a).Take(b).ToArray();
```

Then you can have a string , includes continuous chars of c :

```
string r = new string(c);
```

for example , i have this text in a file :

*hello how are you ?*

i use this code :

```
char[] c = File.ReadAllText(FilePath).ToCharArray().Skip(6).Take(3).ToArray();               
string r = new string(c);
MessageBox.Show(r);
```

and it shows : **how**

Way 2

Very simple :
Using **Substring method**

```
string s = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
string r = s.Substring(6,3);
MessageBox.Show(r);
```

Good Luck ;

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
{
    // seek to starting point
    fileStream.Position = 977;

    // read
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to read specific data types from files `System.IO.BinaryReader` is the best choice.
if you are not sure about file encoding use

```
        using (var binaryreader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path)))
        {
            // seek to starting point
            binaryreader.ReadChars(977);
            // read
            char[] data = binaryreader.ReadChars(200);
            //do what you want with data
        }
```

else if you know character size in source file size are 1 or 2 byte use

```
        using (var binaryreader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(path)))
        {
            // seek to starting point
            binaryreader.BaseStream.Position = 977 * X;//x is 1 or 2 base on character size in sourcefile
            // read
            char[] data = binaryreader.ReadChars(200);
            //do what you want with data
        }
```